# SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDb - does anybody have a link to the download page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016-localdb

The link to download page of SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDb (https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=52679) is no longer working.

I have searched left and right on the Download Center, and also lot of websites online for this, but it's not available.

Can anybody say whether this has been withdrawn or anything?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Scott Hanselman [made](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSqlServerExpress.aspx) life easy.

Answer (score 2):

To get the install, download the setup for SQL Server Express and one of the options is to "Download Media" and from there you can select "Local DB" and you get the MSI.